# How to bring an application to front of another one which is currently running?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launching-application

I Have an android application in which I handled the device Home button click.I made the application relaunched automatically when user clicks on Home button while my application is running using **Service**.
When user clicks on Home button while running my application , shows default home screen and then shows again the activity.
But my problem is that is takes some long time to show last activity of my application from home screen.ie,the home screen  is displayed for a long  time.Because of this user can launch any other application from home screen and my application runs in background.ie,When pressing BACk button after launching another application it is possible to view my application.
Is it possible to avoid this delay and bring my application to front of that launched app?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Place the `Home button` Code in your `AsyncTask` `doinBackground()` or you can use `Handler`. That would help you in reducing the delay of loading the `activity`. For more information on How to use AsyncTask and Handler, check this link: [Android Background Processing](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: I did not use  an AsyncTask.Its a service

Comment: @DevuSoman i have edited the answer.. Please check and try to implement in that way...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I implement a **countdown timer** in my service that repeatedly start my activity in `onStick`. When my activity comes to the foreground, in `onNewIntent` I send a message to the service to cancel the **countdown timer**. It works out pretty well.